# Not able to connect to a remote SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, powershell-2.0

I am trying to find a solution to my problem online but no luck yet. Hence posting the question:

I am running a `powershell` script which will fetch backup details from all `SQL Servers` mentioned in a notepad. The script is working fine for `SQL Servers` till `2008R2`. But I am getting error while connecting to `SQL Server 2012/2014`. The script is running on `Windows Server 2008` having `SQL Server 2008R2` installed on it. So I will request you to help me to troubleshoot it.

---

Input File:E:\Sachin\SQL_Servers2.txt

SERVERNAME,SERVERNAME,1433

---

```
$servers = Get-Content 'E:\Sachin\SQL_Servers2.txt'
#Create a new Excel object using COM 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)

#Counter variable for rows
$global:intRow = 1

foreach ($sv in $servers) {
# Separate the server and instance names
$srvr = $sv.Split(",")
$server = $srvr[0]
$instance = $srvr[1]
$port = $srvr[2]

getsqlinfo $server $instance $port


function getsqlinfo {
param (
  [string]$svr,
  [string]$inst,
  [string]$port
  )


foreach ($instancename in $inst)
{

 #Create column headers
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "INSTANCE NAME:"
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = $instancename
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1).Font.Bold = $True
 $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2).Font.Bold = $True

 $global:intRow++

  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "DATABASE NAME"
  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "LAST FULL BACKUP"
  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "LAST DIFFERENTIAL BACKUP"
  $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "FULL BACKUP AGE(DAYS)"

 #Format the column headers
 for ($col = 1; $col -le 4; $col++)
 {
      $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Font.Bold = $True
      $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
      $Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,$col).Font.ColorIndex = 34
 }

 $global:intRow++
  #######################################################
 #This script gets SQL Server database information using PowerShell

 $ConnectionString = "data source = $inst,$port; initial catalog = master; trusted_connection = true;"

             [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

 # Create an SMO connection to the instance
 $s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server')

 $s.ConnectionContext.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

 $dbs = $s.Databases

 #Formatting using Excel


 ForEach ($db in $dbs)
```

Error Msg:

```
The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Failed to connect to server .".
At E:\sachin\BackupDetailsVersion7.ps1:51 char:8
+ ForEach <<<<  ($db in $dbs)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

Pre-Checks Done:

1. I am able to telnet the target SQL Server from the Server where I am running the script.
2. I am having access to the target SQL Server as well.
3. Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP2,Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP2 Shared Management Objects and Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP2 are already installed on the target Server.
4. Execution policy is set to unrestricted on the target Server.

I am able to get the SQL Server details on the target machine when checking locally, but not able to get details from other machine.

I am suspecting whether is there any restriction/limitation to connect between different SQL Server versions through `powershell` (any kind of compatibility issue).

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The error says you tried to connect to the *local* server (`.`). What server name did you use? Did you try to specify the remote server's name or IP? Other than that, it's impossible to help with a custom script if you don't post the relevant code, input and errors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to connect to a SQL Server installed on some other Windows Server but the server/instance name is not visible in the error message. I also dont have any idea about it. I am mentioning the  remote server's name only. I will share the relevant piece of the code in the question itself. Thanks :)

Comment: The name *is* visible. It is `.` . The error message is `"Failed to connect to server .` Your code reads the connection details from a file. Are you sure these values are OK? Furthermore, your code uses the *instance name* as a server name. Are the values mixed up perhaps?

Comment: In other words, forget about incompatibilities and debug your code. The message is very explicit and the code does some weird things. At the very least, print out the connection string before actually connecting so you know what is going on

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The same code is working perfectly fine when i am mentioning the other SQL Server 2000,2005 and 2008R2 servers but not in case of SQL Server 2012. So i am sure there is no problem with the code. Server name and instance name is same because it is a default instance. I printed $ConnectionString and it looks perfeclty fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The error is clear and the wrong parameters are obvious. The code is definitely buggy. Check the file and the print out the connection string before using it. "Think horses not zebras" applies 100% here. Why would you assume that a connectivity error has anything to do with compatiblity? Debug the code *first*, then start looking for compatibility problems